# how to find all parent in mssql query

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_no int DEFAULT 0,
    name varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Locations', 0);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('NSW', 1);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('QLD', 1);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('VIC', 1);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Sydney', 2);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Brisbane', 3);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Melbourne', 4);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Sydney Head Office', 5);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Brisbane Head Office', 6);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Melbourne Head Office', 7);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Level 21 Martin Place', 8);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Level 22 Martin Place', 8);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Level 23 Martin Place', 8);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Level 24 Martin Place', 8);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('First Floor', 9);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Ground Floor', 9);
INSERT INTO foo (name, parent_no) VALUES ('Second Floor', 9);
```

how to find all parent if where id=11 name="Level 21 Martin Place"

code in the [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/57e93/1)

Comment: Well done for trying, but have you tried running that query? It doesn't work. Please also update your post for expected value. Thanks.

Comment: look my code in sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/57e93/1

Comment: I've edited the new code into your question.  Expected output will still be appreciated though.

Comment: what is the expected result ? also check out https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: all parent from child if i'm select Level 21 Martin Place with id=11, and parent id=8 name="Sydney Head Office", and id=5 name="Sydney", id=2 and name="NSW" and ends id=1 name="Locations"

Comment: this name of the parent is taken from where?

Comment: if you are using two tables then you want to use join operation

Comment: name of the parent is taken from id

Comment: @MarshallTelaumbanua please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49363230/edit) your question with expected results in a **readable** format. I can't ask this any more times than I have.

Comment: `Recursive CTE` is the answer !

Comment: ok @Larnu i will edit as i expect

Comment: How to using Recursive CTE @Squirrel

Comment: refer to the link i posted earlier

Comment: @Squirrel how answer without Recursive CTE ?

Comment: then it is while loop